# Remove hard coded runningUser in dashboard?

Tags: salesforcedx, dashboard

I have created a dashboard, and every time I download it using sfdx, it save my email as the runningUser for my dashboard.  Clearly this is incorrect as when I package it, my customers are not going to have the same user as me.  How do I remove it so that it can just be whoever the viewer is?  Instead of being hardcoded to me.

```
Part of the dasbboard xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dashboard xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <backgroundEndColor>#FFFFFF</backgroundEndColor>
    <backgroundFadeDirection>Diagonal</backgroundFadeDirection>
    <backgroundStartColor>#FFFFFF</backgroundStartColor>
    <chartTheme>light</chartTheme>
    <colorPalette>unity</colorPalette>
    <dashboardChartTheme>light</dashboardChartTheme>
    <dashboardColorPalette>unity</dashboardColorPalette>
    <dashboardGridLayout>...</dashboardGridLayout>
    <dashboardType>LoggedInUser</dashboardType>
    <description>My Dashboard Description</description>
    <isGridLayout>true</isGridLayout>
    <runningUser>my@email.com</runningUser>
    <textColor>#000000</textColor>
    <title>My Dashboard</title>
    <titleColor>#000000</titleColor>
    <titleSize>12</titleSize>
</Dashboard>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when deployed the runningUser is automatically set by Salesforce to whoever the installer is, per documentation in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_dashboard.htm

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option to run the dashboard as the "dashboard viewer"? In the dashboard settings there is this option:

[image: Setting]

If installed with your email selected it will just set the "View Dashboard As" to "Another Person" with your package as the name. So after install this can be changed to the correct value or you can leave it up to the dashboard viewer.